# Finding attributes of function enclosing a closure/lambda

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have an extension function as such...

```
public static class EventLibrary
{
    [EventCollection]
    public static Event Sequence(this Event ev)
    {
        ev.Started += (args) =>
        {
            // do something!
        }
    }
}
```

I then, inside Event, I look at the delegate subscribers using the following...

```
var dels = new List<Delegate[]>();
if (Started != null) 
    dels.Add(Started.GetInvocationList());
```

The reason is to try and detect whether the function that created the closure has an attribute, as in this example, `EventCollection`. On the Delegate object, both `DelcaringType` and `ReflectedType` return something like `EventLibrary+<Sequence>c_AnonStorey1` but this is as far as I get.

I would love to do this without any string operations but I'm not sure it's possible... Does anyone know?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Wouldn't it be simpler to just have a separate event for those methods?

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* you are doing this?

Comment: That is an option, yes, but this is my optimal solution. It's not a matter of life or death, I'm just curious. I am writing a 'closure-based event sequencing system' in which part of the appeal is the fact that you can very easily write closures rather than a series of separate functions. See here: https://github.com/acron0/Chancy

Comment: Sounds a bit like a synchronous version of [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)

Comment: Sort of, but this is micro by comparison and has a more specific use area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no way to do that reliably. The closest you can do is to get the `DeclaringType`, but there isn't anything like `DeclaringMethod`.

It seems you already noticed you could try using the name of the lambda method, but doing so would be fragile (what about method overloads?) and might not work the same in other languages (like VB.NET) or future versions of the compiler.

I think the best way to do this is to somehow configure `Event` to tell it what you want. Possibly something like:

```
var eventCollectionEvent = ev.EventCollection;
eventCollectionEvent.Started += …;
```

Comment: Cheers svick, I fear you're right. Your answer has given me an idea for another solution to the problem though, so thanks.